# How to tell when dom-repeat is done stamping elements

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dom, polymer

In Polymer, the `dom-repeat` template helper emits a `dom-change` event whenever it stamps the result of an iteration into the DOM. Is there a way for me to tell when ALL of the iterations are complete?

Comment: Is it possible to determine this by looking at data in the dom change event - knowing what  data item should be last and then checking for that? Perhaps not the ideal solution, however.

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/template/dom-repeat.html  @348 it fires an event at the conclusion of its render()

Comment: as Robert says above the `dom-change` event is fired when the render of the `dom-repeat` template is complete. You should then be able to add to your template the following line of code which will execute a function when this event is fired: `<template is="dom-repeat" on-dom-change="_functionToCall">`

Comment: How Can I distinguish the final `dom-change` event from the other ones though?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this simple example can help explain the behaviour and extend on the comments.

```
<dom-module id="change-tester">
    <template>
    <h1>Change Tester</h1>
        <ul>
        <template id="template" is="dom-repeat" items="{{content}}">
            <li>{{item}}</li>
        </template>
        </ul>
        <button on-click="more">Add more</button>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({

        is: 'change-tester',
        properties: {
            content: {
                type: Array,
                value: function(){ return ["one", "two", "three"]}
            }
        },
        ready: function(){
            this.$.template.addEventListener("dom-change", function(event){
               console.log(event);
            });
        },

        more: function(){
            this.push("content", "four");
            this.push("content", "five");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Whenever `dom-change` is fired, I log the event to the console, so open the dev tools and have a look. Initially, the `dom-repeat` has three iterations and will populate the dom with three elements. Note that only one event will fire, namely when all three elements have been added. If you click the button, two more items are added to the content in the repeat. As the `dom-repeat` updates asynchronously, these two items are again handled in one go and will only trigger one event.

So the `dom-change` event is actually that final event you are looking for. It will only fire again, if you manipulate the items that are bound to it.

Answer (score 4):

To access a dynamically created node in Polymer 1.x (like template repeat)
use:

```
this.$$('#id')
```

For Polymer 2.x use:

```
this.shadowRoot.getElementById('id');
```

instead of `this.$.id`

for example if the template `id` is `template` you should use

```
this.$$('#template')
```

example

```
ready: function(){
    this.$$('#template').addEventListener("dom-change", function(event){
        console.log(event);
    });
},
```